# Is there any way to re-use the reponse that has already been grabbed by scrapy instead of using selenium.webdriver.Chrome().get(response.url)

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, python-3.5

Is there any way to re-use the reponse that has already been grabbed by scrapy instead of using

```
selenium.webdriver.Chrome().get(response.url)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific, what are you going to do with response content?

Comment: @AlekseyDr.   I want to pass response to selenium webdriver to extract some javascript  field element and I want to avoid requesting the same page twice , once by scrapy and once by selenium